# SSMA Image size restriction

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm doing access to sql migration using SSMA.
Post migration. Unable to store image of size more than 1 mb. When I try to add an image of size larger than 1 mb .I get an error which says linked table limitation .unable to save image.\

Is there any size limitation on the linked table for Images.

Comment: No errors for images < 1 mb?

Comment: no.image less than 1 mb works fine